Is there a (mostly) comprehensive list of Eastern Orthodox Saints available?
I feel the title is mostly self explanatory, but I am looking for a list/collection that has most or all of the saints venerated in Eastern Orthodoxy. I have seen some churches have calendars with amounts of saints on them (example: https://www.oca.org/saints/lives), but I am looking for greater comprehensiveness.

The main text consulted for the sanctoral cycle of the Orthodox church is the Synaxarion. They are traditionally published in 12 volumes (one for each month), but condensed and abbreviated versions are now more popular / available. Note that some saints have been recognized in certain Orthodox jurisdictions but not in others.

Was about to basically say the same thing. Not sure that anything has higher comprehensiveness.
